# Accesar una variable session desde jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery

Desde jquery, envío a validar un usuario vía Ajax, validación que está en un PHP. Si la validación está Ok, el PHP mete al usuario en una variable de sesión:

```
<?php
$_SESSION['nombre']=$usuario;
```

Luego, imprimo dicha variable en el html:

```
<div>
<?php echo "Usuario Logueado:[".$_SESSION['nombre']." ]";?>         
</div>
```

Finalmente, desde jquery vía Ajax, envío información para grabar en mysql en otro PHP. Desde este PHP, trato de acceder a la variable de sesión para grabar el usuario, pero no la reconoce;

```
<?php
require_once ("funciones/conexiones.php");
$ven=$_SESSION['nombre'];
```

Revisando en la consola, arroja:

Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION

Por qué no puedo acceder al valor almacenado en la variable _SESSION ?

Desde ya, muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Adicionalmente, traté de imprimir la variable de sesión en el jquery:

```
$(document).on('change', '.cmb_articulo', function () 
{
alert($_SESSION['nombre']);
```

pero me arroja: ReferenceError: $_SESSION is not defined

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Dónde se inicia la sesión?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parece que el problema es que no estás iniciando la sessión. Añade [`session_start`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php) al principio de tus ficheros PHP para iniciar la sesión y entonces ya no deberías recibir ese error y se pasará bien la variable de sesión sin necesidad de usar JavaScript (algo que no te recomendaría para lo que intentas).

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once ("funciones/conexiones.php");
$ven=$_SESSION['nombre'];
```

Prueba eso y dime si sigues teniendo problemas.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Alvaro Montoro, tienes toda la razón, fue un error de mi parte. Gracias por tu tiempo y respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Estas Mezclando 2 cosas, el jquery y el php.

No se si funcionará, pero debería ser algo como esto.

```
$(document).on('change', '.cmb_articulo', function () 
{
alert(<?=$_SESSION['nombre']?>);
```